# Magento - PayPal not redirecting to mobile site

Tags: php, magento, mobile, paypal

On my Magento store I have a problem with PayPal. Magento is not redirecting PayPal payments to the mobile PayPal template if the customer is using a mobile phone or tablet. I contacted PayPal and they let me know that the variable "discount_amount_cart" should be removed in order to redirect customers to the mobile PayPal site.

I'm using the standard, built-in PayPal Website Payments Standard payment method. I searched the internet, but I can't find out what the consequences are when I remove that variable, and how I can do that.

Do you have any idea?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got an answer back from PayPal: Unfortunately, there is no workaround for this currently. You cannot use the discount parameter and still use the mobile optimized checkout.

Bummer! We have to use the default website. Thank you, Simon H, for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The only place this variable seems to be set is in this method: `Mage_Paypal_Model_Api_Standard::getStandardCheckoutRequest()`. In my opinion the discount should not be related to the mobile page, but you can try to remove it anyway.

`discount_amount_cart` is a optional field:

> Single discount amount charged cart-wide. 
>   It must be less than the selling price of all items combined in the cart. This variable >overrides any individual item discount_amount_x values, if present. 
>   Applies only to the Cart Upload command.
>    -- [PayPal - HTML Variables for Shopping Carts](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/#id08A6HH0D0TA)

Comment: Hi Simon, thank you for your answer. I thought the same but the PayPal Technical Support said that to me. Do you have an idea where I can disable discount_amount_cart?

Comment: Check the lines `if (isset($request['discount_amount'])) {
                $request['discount_amount_cart'] = $request['discount_amount'];
            }` in `app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Api/Standard.php`.

Comment: Thanks! I will test that settings in my test environment. I wil let you know if it works!

Comment: Thank you! It's working! But, one problem. If I apply a discount to products and add a coupon code, the discount is not applied in the PayPal mobile environment now. How can we fix that?

Comment: Glad you are making progress. As we removed the discount amount from the request to PayPal this makes sense. Gives the PayPal support some more hints? A solution could be to pass only the cart amount and don't display the cart content in the PayPal cart with `display` request variable.

Comment: Nope, PayPal has instantly closed the ticket. I will reopen it and ask for more information. I think that it will take a couple of days to get a response from them. Keep you posted!